# Can I increase the speech_recognition listen timeout on the device?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to use the speech to text function in Android studio and flutter. However, I understand that the timeout is set to 2-3 seconds. What I need is at least 10 seconds. So can I slow down the timeout on the device or on the code?

`final TextEditingController _pauseForController = TextEditingController(text: '3'); final TextEditingController _listenForController = TextEditingController(text: '30');`

The _listenFor statement here is the time when the voice comes in, and I've tried changing the listening mode, but it doesn't work. I also tried modifying the timeout parameter, but it doesn't apply.

and Is it possible to increase the timeout using hacking on a non-code device?